# PHPUnit mock with multiple expects() calls

Tags: mocking, phpunit, expectations

Using PHPUnit, I wonder how we can have multiple expectation from the same stub/mock.

For example, I want to test that the mock will have the method `display()` called and return NULL. I also want to test that the method `process()` will be called.

In fact my test is called `testProcessIsCalledIfDisplayReturnNull()`.

So I need to setup 2 expectations on the same mock object, and the manual doesn't really help about that :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know, that method is called once use $this->once() in expects(), otherwise use $this->any()

```
$mock = $this->getMock('nameOfTheClass', array('firstMethod','secondMethod','thirdMethod'));
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('firstMethod')
     ->will($this->returnValue('value'));
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('secondMethod')
     ->will($this->returnValue('value'));
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('thirdMethod')
     ->will($this->returnValue('value'));
```

Comment: As I understand it once() should only be used when it's considered important that the method is called exactly once - when code that called the method more or less than once should be considered broken. If the current implementation calls it once, but it would be fine to change it to zero or more in future then use any(). That makes it easier to change the code in future.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried this, and it seems to works as long as the call order stays good:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('mockWorker', array('display', 'process'));
$mock->expects($this->exactly(1))
     ->method('display')
     ->will($this->returnValue(null));
$mock->expects($this->exactly(1))
     ->method('process');
```

Comment: You can use `once()` instead of `exactly(1)`. Keep in mind that this doesn't create an ordering between the two expectations, but it's usually good enough. If you require specific ordering, use `at($index)`.