# PHPUnit: expects method meaning

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, mocking, phpunit

When I create a new mock I need to call the expects method. What exactly it does? What about its arguments?

```
$todoListMock = $this->getMock('\Model\Todo_List');
        $todoListMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getItems')
            ->will($this->returnValue(array($itemMock)));
```

I can't find the reason anywhere (I've tried docs). I've read the sources but I can't understand it.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> expects() - Sets how many times you expect a method to be called:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('nameOfTheClass', array('firstMethod','secondMethod','thirdMethod'));
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('firstMethod')
     ->will($this->returnValue('value'));
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('secondMethod')
     ->will($this->returnValue('value'));
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('thirdMethod')
     ->will($this->returnValue('value'));
```

> If you know, that method is called once use $this->once() in expects(), otherwise use $this->any()

see:
[PHPUnit mock with multiple expects() calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834416/phpunit-mock-with-multiple-expects)

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs

http://www.slideshare.net/mjlivelyjr/advanced-phpunit-testing

Comment: What happens if its called once, and then, called again?

Comment: if method expected to be called once will be called more times, test will probably fail

Comment: There a missing ) and the end of each ->will().

Comment: I like to know the reason behind method expects(). All I can see is that If I give argument of any() it will work however. Seems like this method is not necessary while mocking object. I need to understand further on this subject. I know there must be a reason for this.

Comment: @ApitJohnIsmail so did you ever look into the library?

Comment: There is also `->willReturn('value)`.

Answer (score 56):

A look into the source code will tell you:

```
/**
 * Registers a new expectation in the mock object and returns the match
 * object which can be infused with further details.
 *
 * @param  PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Invocation $matcher
 * @return PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker
 */
public function expects(PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Invocation $matcher);
```

And the PHPUnit Manual lists the available Matchers at

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers

> - **any()** returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is executed zero or more times.
> - **never()** returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is never executed.
> - **atLeastOnce()** returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is executed at least once.
> - **once()** returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is executed exactly once.
> - **exactly(int $count)** returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is executed exactly $count times.
> - **at(int $index)** returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is invoked at the given $index.

Comment: Note that at() starts at 0. I found that out the hard way through some trial and error today.

Comment: Also note that `at()` uses the same counter for ALL stubbed method on your mock object. It does NOT assign a new counter to each method.