# How to reset expectations on PHPUnit mock object

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a large amount of tests in a TestCase. I want to set up a mock object that returns the same value in most of the tests, but in a few of the tests I would like to customize that value.

My idea was to create a `set_up()` method (I was unable to set expectations inside the automatically invoked `setUp()`), and to manually call it at the beginning of each test. In this method, I would set the default return value, then in the few tests that need to customize the return value, I would call expects a second time, and hopefully overwrite the default return value. This does not work, the return value is not overwritten.

Here is a simplified example:

```
<?php

class SomeClass {
    function someMethod() {
    }
}

class SomeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $mock;

    function set_up() {
        $this->mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor() // This is necessary in actual program
            ->getMock();
        $this->mock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('someMethod')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1));
    }

    function test() {
        $this->set_up();

        $this->mock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('someMethod')
            ->will($this->returnValue(2));

        $this->assertEquals(2, $this->mock->someMethod());
    }
}
```

It seems that this should be possible from reading [How to reset a Mock Object with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302102/how-to-reset-a-mock-object-with-phpunit).

[PHPUnit mock with multiple expects() calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834416/phpunit-mock-with-multiple-expects-calls) does not answer my question.

I am using phpUnit 4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass arguments to set_up method so it can configure the mock as needed:

```
function set_up($someMethodReturnValue = 1) {
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor() // This is necessary in actual program
        ->getMock();
    $mock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('someMethod')
        ->will($this->returnValue($someMethodReturnValue));
    return $mock;
}


function test() {
    $mock = $this->set_up(2);
    $this->assertEquals(2, $this->mock->someMethod());
}
```

You can further enhance the set_up() method. Eventually you could create a Mock creation class if there are lots of options.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to reuse the mock, I just want to overwrite a default expectation. I would call `set_up()` in each test so that the mock is not shared between tests. Passing the returnValue in as an argument is a good idea, though.

Comment: right, the problem I stated does not occur. I'll edit the answer.